# Notify doesnt work.. waitng forever thread Java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify, forever

Hello I am new to programming and I am trying to do a simple Producer-Consumer problem..but unfortunately my thread waits forever..notify doesnt work..any ideas? :/

```
public synchronized void order() throws Exception{

    System.out.println("User "+name+" requests:\n"+"cherries=" + cherries);

    while(checkValues()==true){
        System.out.println(name+"  waiting");
        wait(); 
    } 
    notify();
    Update();
    store.toString();

    System.out.println(name+" gets resources ");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
 }
```

Comment: `notify()` works perfectly well. Your assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: You haven't shown us enough code to diagnose the problem.  We would also need to see the bit where you are waiting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not ... `wait()` and `notify()` work just fine.

The problem is that you are not using them correctly.

```
while(checkValues()==true){
    System.out.println(name+"  waiting");
    wait(); 
}
notify();
```

This is going to wait until some other thread notifies the `this` instance for the method call.  That cannot be the `notify();` call after the loop ...'cos you cannot get there until you've been notified.

Now it is *possible* that some other thread could be doing that `notify()`, but you haven't shown us the code that does that.  And the current code doesn't indicate that.  And the symptoms you describe point that way too.

---

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out what your code is actually trying to do.  It really doesn't make much sense to me.  So I can't suggest how to fix it.

The best I can do is suggest that you read some tutorial examples of the right way to use wait/notify.  For instance:

- http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/
- http://java67.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/producer-consumer-problem-with-wait-and-notify-example.html

Comment: "you cannot get there until you've been notified." made me LOL. +1